# Sort the following numbers into 4 different set

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Sort the following 16 numbers into 4 sets of 4 and give an explanation for each grouping:

$\{1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8, 9, 11, 13, 17, 25, 32, 49, 128\}$

This is the result I got

$$\{4,9,25,49\} - \text{Square numbers}$$
$$\{5,11,13,17\} - \text{Prime Numbers}$$
$$\{4,8,32,128\} - \text{Integer powers of 2}$$
$$\{1,2,3,5\} - \text{Terms in the Fibonacci sequence}$$

I was wondering if there are other possible results.

Comment: My last comment was mean and irritable.  But if the rules are to put in 4 sets, *anything* is acceptable.  So my answer is {1,2,3,4}{4,5,8,9}{5,11,13,17}{25,32,49,128}.  Explation:  because that's what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That division is as good as any.  Head over to [OEIS](http://oeis.org) to have your mind completely blown.